# Error interpolating in Qgis

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, interpolation, qgis-2

I'm trying to interpolate with the algorithm "v.surf.idw" in Qgis version 2.18 Las Palmas.

The data that i'm using are points whose coordinates were loaded by a CSV file, these the guade as a new shape type layer. From the attributes of the points I am interested in interpolating with respect to "Rendimiento".

[image]

the formats of the attributes are the following:

[image]

When I run the algorithm the result is as follows.

[image]

[image]

When reviewing the registration message this is what it throws.

[image]